# With which number should I multiply $z = a + i b$ to rotate it by 45 degrees

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, rotations

​Multiplying​ ​a​ ​non​ ​zero​ ​complex​ ​number​ ​$z$​ ​by​ the imaginary unit $i$​ ​is​ ​equivalent​ ​to​ ​a ​counter​ ​clockwise​ 90​ ​degrees​ rotation ​in​ ​the​ ​complex​ ​plane.​ Instead, a ​counter​ ​clockwise​ ​rotation​ ​by​ ​45 degrees​ ​results​ ​from​ ​multiplying​ ​$z$​ ​by which number?

Comment: Rotation anticlockwise through angle $t$ is multiplication by $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$.

Answer (score 3):

$z = a + ib = |z| e^{i\theta}$

Then if we take $w = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$

$zw = |z|e^{i(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4})}$

In other words, thats rotate $z$ $45$ degrees

Comment: Actually i am given a choice of 
a) ie^-( i pi/4)
b) e^(i pi/2)
c) -i /4
d) 4i
e) none of the above

Comment: Option a), $i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ so $ie^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}  = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2} - i\frac{\pi}{4}} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$

Answer (score 0):

Although the correct answer has already been given, namely $\frac{\sqrt2}2(1+i)$, I think it is worth pointing out, that provided you agree to replace the word "rotation" with "similarity", it is a safe bet that the most natural answer would be $1+i$ :
Let $s:\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}, z=x+iy \mapsto u+iy=(1+i)z=(1+i)(x+iy)=(x-y,x+y)$.

Then $s(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})\subset \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\{1,i\}$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Then the matrix of $s$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1 &-1 \\1 & 1\end{bmatrix} $. You can illustrate $s$ with drawings such that :
[image]